# How to access other controls values in ITemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to have a control with template supporting so I can put a control on it and I can access them just by their name( just the way UpdatePanels do)
for instance:

```
<uc1:FramePanel ID="FramePanel1" runat="server">
    <MessageTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"></asp:Button>
    </MessageTemplate>
</uc1:FramePanel>
```

and then in my code could access Button1 like that:

```
Button1.Text="dsdsdsds";
```

for now I can access it using find control and I am not happy with it

If you look at updatepanel you can access its control directly

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"></asp:Button>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

You can access button1 just easily:

```
Button1.Text="dsdsdsds";
```

thanks heaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your template is not going to repeat itself then In the templated control, you can decorate your template as TemplateInstance.Single.

```
[TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)]
```

This would help you access the controls inside the template at page level

Comment: Thanks Ramesh it was so helpfull to me